# Open VSCode and attach to container from terminal

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

I would like to open VSCode from the terminal, but instead of opening a directory or file, I would like to attach the VSCode session to a running container using the `Dev Containers` extension.

I have tried using the `--folder-uri` flag with the `vscode-remote` option as suggested [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/110050) (i.e., `code --folder-uri=vscode-remote://<container name> --verbose`) which does not seem to open anything.